# How do I instrument my python code?

Tags: python, grok

I'm developing some web apps with the grok framework, and I want to know what the framework is doing when serving a simple page.

So, what tools are out there to grab such data, and maybe, graph it?

Comment: What do you expect to get as the output? "Is there something that will make pictures of something that my app is doing" isn't much to go on. The `trace` module will record what functions / statements get executed, but it's a pretty low-level tool, you'd have to mine anything useful out of its output yourself.

Comment: Are you doing this out of curiosity (because then one set of tools will be appropriate), or because your application is not performing well and you would like it to perform better (in which case another set of tools will be more appopropriate)?

Comment: @BrandonCraigRhodes It's just for curiosity. I want to get an idea on what is the thing doing.

Comment: @Inerdia Ideally i should get a graph on the function calls during a request process.

Comment: @NoeNieto You can't really have a graph with one axis. Regardless, tracing *should* get you that data, but without producing any "pretty" output.

Answer (score 0):

Python has plenty of built-in reflectivity that could be used for instrumentation. For example:

```
def hax_all_the_things():
  for x in list(globals()):
    func = globals()[x]
    if callable(func) and not hasattr(func, 'instrumented'):
      globals()[x] = lambda func = func, *args, **kwargs: (
        __import__('sys').stdout.write("HAX\n"), func(*args, **kwargs)
      )[1]
      globals()[x].instrumented = True
```